# Will the Wolfram Cloud products have a palette function?

Tags: palettes

I am going to use the Wolfram Cloud for my class.

Will the Wolfram Cloud products have a palette function?

Comment: Have you asked Wolfram? http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/551841?p_p_auth=2uYS2hOD Currently `CreatePalette` generates a dialog so it is still not there.